# Boxee Box: How to trigger Home-Button in Boxee Browser (KEYBOARD_MODE)?

Tags: javascript, browser, boxee

How can I get the back/home button working in boxee box browser? F.e. I want to open a menu if user clicks enter and want to close it with back button?

I was just writing a function which triggered all received keycodes in the boxee browser (browser in boxee.KEYBOARD_MODE). I received every keyboard key, but I couldn't get an event for the play/pause button.
If I was pressing the back/home button, the application shows the dialog to close the browser and I didn't receive a keycode too. Are these buttons functional buttons which cannot be modified?! Or is there a way to override the buttons behaviour?

Best, K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually control what those buttons do by setting the relevant callbacks in your controller file.

You would be interested in onKeyboardKeyBack, onPause and onPlay.

It's pretty well documented here: 
http://developer.boxee.tv/Control_Script_Context
http://developer.boxee.tv/JavaScript_API#Keyboard_Mode

For example, you can override the behavior of the back button using something like:

```
boxee.onKeyboardKeyBack = function() {
  var pathname = browser.execute('window.location.pathname');
  switch (pathname) {
    case 'boxee':
      browser.shutdown();
    break;
    default:
      browser.back();
    break;
  } 
};
```

Note that it seems like browser.execute() will only return strings, so you can't do things like:
    var location = browser.execute('window.location');
    alert('location.pathname');

Answer (score 0):

and just as an update, with the new api it is now possible to trigger menu/back button and play/pause button without the native overlay!

http://developer.boxee.tv/JavaScript_API#Keyboard_Mode